# JavaScript - Dictionary is empty

Tags: javascript, dictionary, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm using Appcelerator and I want to know if my dictionary in JS is empty.

I've tried this:

```
var options = {};

// Option 1
Object.keys(options).length
1

//Option 2
isEmpty(options)
false

function isEmpty(ob){
      for(var i in ob){ if(ob.hasOwnProperty(i)){return false;}}
      return true;
}

//Option 3
JSON.stringify(options) === '{}'
false
```

Comment: What does `console.log.log(options)` show you? The first option is telling you there is one property, so what is it? Log it and see.

Comment: I don't know why shows one property. The console shows: options = {}

Comment: Weird. So then `console.log(Object.keys(options))`?

Comment: My code: `Ti.API.debug("Keys: " + Object.keys(options).length + " / Dict: " + JSON.stringify(options));`

Comment: Console: `Keys: 1 / Dict: {}`

Comment: But what is the key? Log `Object.keys(options)`, not the .length, so we can see what the first key is. Could that property (whatever it is) have a value that was set to undefined, or to a function? Either would be ignored by JSON. stringify.

Comment: Thank you, you're right. I had a key with undefined value.

Comment: @kova could you add the final solution as an answer you an accept so that the question shows as answered?

Comment: @FokkeZandbergen done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the problem: I added one key with value 'undefined' and the `JSON.stringify()` function didn't show me that key.

So, this function `Object.keys(options).length` works perfectly.

Caution with keys with value 'undefined', check this with this function `Object.keys(options)` because `JSON.stringify` return an empty dictionary `{}`

```
var dict = {
   cat: undefined
}

Ti.API.debug("Dict: " + JSON.stringify(dict)) >  Dict: {}
Ti.API.debug("Keys: " + Object.keys(options).length) > Keys: 1
Ti.API.debug("Keys str: " + Object.keys(options)) > Keys: cat

var dict = {}

Ti.API.debug("Dict: " + JSON.stringify(dict)) >  Dict: {}
Ti.API.debug("Keys: " + Object.keys(options).length) > Keys: 0
Ti.API.debug("Keys str: " + Object.keys(options)) > Keys:
```